# AsynTask fields are null

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have an AsyncTask and i want to store some informations in the 
fields of this class. I have something like this:

```
public class NFCReaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String Year = null;
    private String Month = null;
    private String Day = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // do some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do some stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        // do some stuff
        // here my fields are filled with all informations

        log.v("This First", "" + getYear());
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return Year;
    }
    public String getMonth() {
        return Month;
    }
    public String getDay() {
        return Day;
    }
}
```

In My Activity i do that:

```
public void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
    // ...

    NFCReaderTask startReaderTask = new NFCReaderTask(dataDevice);
    startReaderTask.execute();
    startReaderTask.get();

    log.v("This Second", "" + startReaderTask.getYear()); // but this is printed out first

    // ...
}
```

But the values are all null. Why are my fields filled with information
at the last lines of my onPostExecute method but null after the .execute()
of the AsyncTask?

EDIT:

I added some log outputs and noticed, that the log outputs from my activity
are printed out before the log outputs of my AsyncTask. Does that mean
that AsyncTask#get() does not work?

Comment: You should never use get as it will wait for the thread to finish executing. You also should 1000% not use the answer you accepted, which is to run a while loop until the AsyncTask stops running to delay execution of the code. You should use a callback. See my answer below.

Comment: You also do not need and should not use getter methods. An AsyncTask runs asynchronously which means it does not follow the flow of your normal code. You do not know when it will return an answer. Thus getters are inappropriate because there may very well be no value when you call them. Using a callback/interface which is only triggered once the task is completed solves this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are null because at least in the code provided, you never supply their values. You need to either use setter methods to set the values for year, month, and day before execution, or you need to supply data as arguments in the execute() method and retrieve the parameters. For example:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String...params){
    String year = params[0];
    String month = params[1];
    String day = params[2];
}
```

If your problem is that you are not returning values from the `AsyncTask`, that's because `AsyncTask` does not return values like a normal method. As a general rule, you should not use the get() method to get values either. Instead define an interface in your `AsyncTask` and use it to callback to your starting activity or fragment with the results. For example:

```
public interface ReaderTaskCallback{
    public void onTaskComplete(String year, String month, String day);
}
```

Set the interface when you create the `AsyncTask` by adding a setCallback method

```
//In your AsyncTask
private ReaderTaskCallback mCallback;

public void setCallback(ReaderTaskCallback callback){
    mCallback = callback;
}

//In your activity
NFCReaderTask startReaderTask = new NFCReaderTask(dataDevice);
startReaderTask.setCallback(new ReaderTaskCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(String year, String month, String day){
       //use results
    }

});
```

To get the results back from the task just call the callback method when your task is done like this:

```
mCallback.onTaskComplete(year, month, day);
```

The values will be passed back to your activity or fragment when they are ready.

Comment: the problem is i cant set the values in the doInBackground. I have to set them in the onPostExecute so i cant call AsyncTask#wait().

Comment: you could call the get methods in onPreExecute() or you could make a constructor for the asynctask.  You could also pass one highlevel object on execute you change your asynctask to <MyObject,Void, Void>

Comment: What do you mean you have to set them in onPostExecute? I'm confused. If you mean you don't have the values until after the task has completed onDoInBackground than you should use my approach and call the callback method in your onPostExecute. Do the work in the background, return your results to onPostExecute  or set the member values for that task, then call the callback onPostExecute to return values to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any date parameters from anywhere, if you did you'd also then need to add a constructor to your NFCReaderTask class...

```
public NFCReaderTask(String year, String month, String day) {
    Year = year;
    Month = month;
    Day = day;
}
```

Set the task with date parameters, such as:

```
new NFCReaderTask("2014", "10", "16").execute();
```

BTW if your date values are integers, you don't need to pass them along as strings:

```
new NFCReaderTask(2014, 10, 16).execute();
```